# Measure of the complement of a sequence of measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory

Under a general measure space, let $E_n$ be a sequence of measurable sets with $\mu(X\backslash E_n)\rightarrow0$ and let $G$ be the set of $x\in X$ that belong to only finitely many sets $E_n$. Show $G$ is measurable and that $\mu(G)=0$.

For the measurable part I looked at $G^c$ which is equivalent to the $lim inf$ of $E_n$. Since this is the union of intersections of measurable sets it must be measurable. Since a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under complements $G$ is measurable.

Maybe by contradiction? Suppose $\mu(G)>0$. Then $\mu(X\backslash G)<\mu(X)$. Moreover since by assumption $\mu(E_n\backslash G)\rightarrow\mu(E_n)\rightarrow\mu(X)$, for some $N$ we have $\mu(X\backslash G)<\mu(X\backslash E_N)$, a contradiction since $E_N\subset X$.

Comment: Any condition on the $E_n$; nested, pairwise -disjoint, etc.?

Comment: No just that they are measurable and that $\mu(X\backslash  E_n)\rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that $G$ is measurable note that $G^c$ is equivalent to the $$\displaystyle{\liminf(E_n)=\cap_{N=1}^{\infty}\cup_{n=N}^{\infty}E_n},$$ that is the set of $x\in X$ such that $x\in E_n$ for all but finitely many $n$. Since this is the union of intersections of measurable sets it must be measurable. Since a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under complements $G$ is measurable.

By assumption we have that $\mu(X\backslash E_n)=\mu({E_n}^c)\rightarrow 0$. Now looking at $(G^c)^c$ we have

$$\left(\cap_{N=1}^{\infty}\cup_{n=N}^{\infty}E_n\right)^c=\cup_{N=1}^{\infty}\left(\cup_{n=N}^{\infty}E_n\right)^c=\cup_{N=1}^{\infty}\cap_{n=N}^{\infty}{E_n}^c$$

Hence $G$ is equal to the $\limsup{E_n}^c$. As desired $\mu(G)=0$.